# Неверно работает onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Использую библиотеку **higslide**, хочу сделать галерею.
При клике на изображение оно должно увеличиваться, но скрипт просто открывает изображение без возможности закрыть его.

```
<a href="news/images/1.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this);">
  <img id="photo_gallery" src="news/images/1.jpg"/>
</a>
<a href="news/images/2.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this);">
  <img id="photo_gallery" src="news/images/2.jpg"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Ошибки в консоли при клике?

Comment: Правильно работает onclick. Как написали так и делает. Выражение при href - не правильное.

Comment: ошибка в консоле

Comment: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg: 
" localhost/news/images/2.jpg ".

Comment: што зделать из странице штоби заработало, или типи как то менять не знаю што делать

Comment: нашел ошибку, все работаєт, не подключив ../highslide/highslide-with-gallery.js